# Where is DocuSign Client JS SDK for frontend integration?

Tags: docusignapi

I am working on DocuSign integration and I see benefits of integrating in our browser application as we don't need to define all the endpoint if we integrate it in our backend. I found DocuSign.js(maybe SDK?) in their [documentation](https://www.docusign.com/blog/developers/introducing-our-javascript-sdk-docusignjs) and [youtube guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a22wO8MOE1I) which is releaed 1 or 1.5 years ago. However, I also found a documentation page that it said the DocuSign.js will get deprecated in three months. Is there a version 2 or an anternative js library? Do I need to write code from scratch to interact with DocuSign in browser? Any advice or work around appreciated.

I have browsed their developer pages and google search but I couldn't find any good suggestion for frontend integration exception DocuSign.js which is deprecating.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, DocuSign.js is being withdrawn. DocuSign will have a new solution (with examples) for calling the eSign REST API from the browser with an announcement planned for April 2023. Watch the [DocuSign Developer blog](https://www.docusign.com/blog/developers) for an announcement.

Answer (score 0):

We have plenty of SDK options, hopefully one of them fits your workflow.

https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/sdks/

Regards
Adrian
DocuSign Developer Support